# Querying data using partial data match?

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb

Given a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE customers ( 
id    bigint,
email text, 
fullname text,
PRIMARY KEY (id) );
```

I'd like to have the capability to occasionally search using a partial data match on email address or full name.

Apache Cassandra has support for SASI which I think enables this kind of querying.

How would this be done best when using CosmosDB and its Cassandra API?

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB does not have SASI support but there is limited support for secondary indexes with the Cassandra API (see [Wire protocol support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cassandra-support#cql-commands) for details).

You can create an index on `email` with:

```
CREATE INDEX customers_email_idx ON customers (email);
```

And you can query the table with:

```
SELECT id, fullname FROM customers WHERE email = ?
```

But partial matches on `fullname` is a challenge since you need SASI for it. Cheers!

Comment: Thx for replying. I am aware of the secondary index functionality, but that still does not offer partial matching :|